# SharePoint Online: is there way to disconnect a M365group from a SPO-teamsite?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, microsoft365

I gave a lot of M365 group connected sites, with Teams configuration.
For old project I would like

- Delete Teams Team
- Delete M365 group
- Keep SharePointsite with all of the files (and set new security)

Can't find a PowerShell-command for this.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to delete M365 Group:

> Remove-UnifiedGroup -Identity "group name"